# CType function in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, code-translation

Below is code from VB.NET script to set DataSource in RS.exe script file. Could you please help me to convert it into C#?

The whole code is as below.

```vb
Dim dataSources(0) As DataSource
Dim dsr0 As New DataSourceReference
dsr0.Reference = "/Aroh/Data Sources/VIPDataSource"
Dim ds0 As New DataSource
ds0.Item = CType(dsr0, DataSourceDefinitionOrReference) ' <=== This line here
ds0.Name = "DataSource1"
dataSources(0) = ds0
ds.SetItemDataSources("/Aroh/TestMe", dataSources)
```

I tried to convert using `ds0.Item = (DataSourceDefinitionOrReference)dsr0` but that gives me an error.

Comment: Please add appropriate tags to your question, assuming you are working with RS, this may help:http://phil-austin.blogspot.com/2009/02/deploying-reporting-services.html

Answer (score 2):

Either

```
ds0.Item = (DataSourceDefinitionOrReference)dsr0;
```

or

```
ds0.Item = dsr0 as DataSourceDefinitionOrReference;
```

Should be used

Comment: Please note that the C# casting operator (parenthesis) is stricter than CType(). There is no exact equivalent in C# to either DirectCast (which is stricter than C# casting) or CType. This will only make a difference on fringe cases however, but it might happen that a direct conversion might not work.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where direct conversion is not possible, you can add a factory method or constructor overload to the DataSourceDefinitionOrReference class that takes in a DataSourceReference and returns a properly constructed instance.